# trying to call an array from multiple functions in a class

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

(in PHP) Here is my problem, I would like to initialize an array in my class, have the constructor fill it, and then I can use the array's variables in other functions.. when I echo my array in the constructor it works perfectly, but the moment i try to echo it in another function, it gives me something very different.

```
class myProblem
{
    public $phaseArray;

    function myProblem()
    {
        $count1 = 0;
        $metaFile = fopen( 'MyFile.txt', 'r' ) or exit( "Unable to open file!" );
        while( !feof( $metaFile ) )
        {
            $this->phaseArray[0][$count1] = 0;
            $this->phaseArray[1][$count1] = fgets( $metaFile );
            echo $this->phaseArray[1][$count1], $count1, '</br>'; //this part displays well
            $count1++;
        }
        close( $metaFile );
    }

    function displayError()
    {
        foreach( $this->phaseArray as $key => $value )
        {
            echo $key, $value, '</br>'; //this part does not show up correctly
        }
        echo $this->phaseArray[0][2]; //this part does not show up correctly
        echo $this->phaseArray[1][1]; //this part does not show up correctly
    }
}
```

Sorry about the indentation, I could not get it to work.
The correct print out is(from the constructor); 
 0Apple
 1Orange
 3Pear
 4Strawberry

but the second function displays;
0Array
1Array

0Array
0Array

any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Thankyou for your time!

Comment: Note: You should use __construct() as the name of your constructor class. The same-as-the-class-name style was deprecated with PHP5.

Comment: Can you post how you are calling the functions.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I did not know that. I will fix that.

Comment: I called it from another php 
<?php    
  require('myProblem.php');
  $calling = new myProblem();
  $calling -> displayError();
?>

Answer (score 1):

Its correct the way it is displayed, you can decide if its wrong how you fill it or how you are reading the data out of it

You are creating an array with 2 dimensions, in which the second dimension is an array, too. So when you want to output all items of the second dimension, loop it through another foreach:

```
foreach( $this->phaseArray as $key => $values ) {
  foreach( $values as $value ) {
    echo $key, $value, '</br>'; //this part show up correctly
  }
}
```

If you want to know how the array is structured, you can easily print it out with this:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $aVar );
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually seems to work, why though doesn't 
echo $this->phaseArray[0][2]; 
echo $this->phaseArray[1][1];

Comment: also, why does it work fine in the constructor but not in the other function? It is baffling me.

Comment: Try out the example I've added to my answer, maybe you can find the mistake :)

Comment: Thanks I added above what the var_dump provided, it seems all fine. I think it is just that I am used to using java and I must be calling the array wrong. Since all my entries are there.

so let's say in java I would wrote: phaseArray[1][2] it would return "fraMetaTiChar.txt", how could i do that with PHP?